# In Quicksort why does the partitioning step start at low - 1 and high + 1?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

Consider Hoare's partition scheme...(from [wikiepdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme))

```
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[lo]
    i := lo – 1
    j := hi + 1
    loop forever
        do
            i := i + 1
        while A[i] < pivot

        do
            j := j – 1
        while A[j] > pivot

        if i >= j then
            return j
```

Why is initially `i = lo - 1` and not lo and `j = hi + 1` and not `hi`? Isn't this including previous pivots which are already in the final position?

I'd like to understand this first because I've seen some optimization's where this isn't the case.

Comment: One way to answer these types of questions is to ask yourself what would happen if they didn't. You could easily change the code and observe what happens, and from that discover why it's implemented the way it is. Over the years, that kind of experimentation has led me to many important insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Others have already explained that the reason the initial left/right pointers are outside the array is that the first thing this version of the algorithm does it increment and decrement, respectively, bringing those indexes into range.)

> Isn't this including previous pivots which are already in the final position?

Well, this particular variation doesn't do anything with the pivot value, other than record it.

Some (most?) variations actually move the chosen pivot element to the far left or right (when it isn't already one of those), then exclude that slot from the remaining partitioning logic, and finally swap it into place (the median position) at the end of the loop.

However, this particular variant just relies on the partitioning loop to do its thing, so the chosen pivot element may be moved around in the array several times but will eventually wind up in the correct area.

Answer (score 1):

Because using ***do while*** to increase i, and decrease j at the first.

So i will be lo, and j well be hi at the first.

If you want to assign i equal lo, and j equal hi, You can refer to [here](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort)

Answer (score 0):

because the first step inside the do-while loop is

```
i := i +1
```

so it has the same value than lo in the first iteration.
After that the algorithm makes the check if A[i] < pivot

the same with j and hi

it is also possible to do:

```
i := lo
j := hi
```

but then the loop must be head oriented:

```
while A[i] < pivot
    i := i +1
endWhile
```